# Razor - HTML.RAW does not output text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tried all solution proposed to other, similar questions but none of them seems to work.
In essence I am trying to display a table filled with data from collection of models. That in itself is not a problem, however I would like to force razor to generate it always in 3 columns (no matter how many elements we have). My original idea was to do it that way:

```
 <table class="projects-grid">
    <tr>
    @for(int i = 0; i< Model.Count(); i++) 
     {
         if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0) 
         {
             Html.Raw("</tr><tr>");
         }
        var item = Model.ElementAt(i);
        <td class="project-tile"> 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)                
        </td>        
    }
    </tr>    
</table>
```

So in essence every third element I would like Razor to output "" string to add another row to the table. All seems to work fine other than this sting is not present in page source. In debug I can see that this line

```
 Html.Raw("</tr><tr>");
```

Is actually called, but no output in generated page is present.

Any help?
Many thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you tried to just use </tr><tr>? No need to use Html.Raw

Comment: I did. The problem then is that razor cannot find closing bracket for the FOR loop... :(

Comment: Yeah. Just noticed that you have invalid html (unclosed tag) and Razor try to validate it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The reason it's not outputing is because of the context of the razor syntax being executed. In your `if` block,  all code runs as if you were in a regular C# context and the line:

```
Html.Raw("</tr><tr>");
```

Returns an `MvcHtmlString` but you are not doing anything with it. You need to enter an output context:

```
@Html.Raw("</tr><tr>");
```

Comment: You are right. I have just tried this. It seems that <Text> workaround is not needed if you add @ before HTML helper. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I would use a  work around.

Try:

```
<table class="projects-grid">
    <tr>
    @for(int i = 0; i< Model.Count(); i++) 
     {
         if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0) 
         {
             <text>
             @Html.Raw("</tr><tr>")
             </text>
         }
        var item = Model.ElementAt(i);
        <td class="project-tile"> 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)                
        </td>        
    }
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works not because of the wrapped `<text>` but because of the `@`.

Comment: If you did the @ it will throw error because it is wrapped in if statement. That's why you have to escape it with <text></text>

Answer (score 0):

Html.Raw actually used for line break like what you do in c# using /n

For Example:

```
<text>
@html.raw("</tr><tr>")
</text>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Html.Raw

Wraps HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted as HTML markup.
For Example :

Controller

```
public actionresult Htmlraw()
{
    viewbag.message = "Hey friends lets go" + "<br />" + "for chillout";
    return view();
}
```

output

```
@html.raw(viewbag.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing Html.Raw with @( and ) solved the issue for me. Eventhough there were outer @{  and  } ,  it still needed  @( and ) around each Html.Raw statement.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont have a space between the "<" and the first character of your tag

I had "< a href="..., after making it "<a href="... it worked