# How does putting @ before Html.Raw work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I thought that `@` in Razor meant C# code. So, in a code like below I would not bother giving another `@` before `Html.Raw()` because it is already wrapped in C# code:

```
@if (Session["User"] == null)
{
    Html.Raw("Welcome User <br>");
}
```

But turns out, the helper actually needs `@` before it to signify its **context** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17772608/1565402) otherwise it would not generate anything.

Can someone please explain why is that in more detail?

Comment: @user2864740 - good point... it should not be dup neither of "why @ used before string constant", nor "why @ used in identifiers"... I've edited sample to avoid one extra `@`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other post explains exactly why you need the extra `@` symbol in front of the `Html.Row` code.

Basically you can think about it like this:

- the first `@` in front of `if` states that the code in the if block is C# code and it will be parsed as such.
- when the C# code is executed, `Html.Raw(...)` generates an `MvcHtmlString` object but you are not really doing anything with it. If you were writing pure code behind you would perhaps write some code to send the `MvcHtmlString` to the response output buffer or something similar

So, the second `@` that you would need in front of `Html.Raw(..)` is actually a short-hand way of specifying that your want the result of the function to be be rendered in the output context, as opposed to be simply left dangling.

A different example might be helpful. This example is only indirectly related to your Razor question - regarding the concept of executing functions and discarding the result.

Let's say you have the following function definition:

```
  int Add(int a, int b)
  {
      return a + b;
  }
```

Now, you could call this function like this:

```
  Add(2, 3);
```

The code above would perform the addition, but the result will be discarded. You're not doing anything with it. Contrast that with:

```
  Console.WriteLine(Add(2, 3));    // now the result is being written to the console
```