# Write the content of Html.Raw into the document

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to show page errors so I have written the following code:

```
    <div class="errors">
        @{
        ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).ToList()
       .ForEach(e => { Html.Raw($"<span>{e.ErrorMessage}</span>"); });
        }
   </div>
```

The `Html.Raw()` does not output anything. 
[Razor - HTML.RAW does not output text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772553/razor-html-raw-does-not-output-text) suggest writing it like `@Html.Raw` which in my case is not valid

Comment: Your missing the leading `@` - `@Html.Raw(...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is what I have mentioned in my question. as it is inside a C# code, putting a @ won't do any good.

Comment: No - you still need the leading `@` (without it it executes the method but does not write it to the response)

Comment: but didn't work with it either, that's why I asked this question

Comment: The `$` in your code would throw an error :) But if your try `<div>@{Html.Raw("<span>xxx</span>");}</div>` your will not see any output, but if you use `<div>@Html.Raw("<span>xxx</span>")</div>` you will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.ErrorMessage` isn't HTML, so you *must not* use `Html.Raw()`.

Instead, you should use a simple loop:

```
@foreach(var e in ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)) {
  <span>@e.ErrorMessage</span>
}
```

Comment: Very nice, it solved the problem. but still I wonder how to write the Html.Raw  value (for sake of learning)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: `Html.Raw()` returns a value, which you must print on the page.  You can call the `Write` methods (from the base class) directly from a lambda, but the general answer is to use `@foreach` instead of lambdas.